# JSP: Tag library Intellisense problem in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, taglib

I am trying to develop a JSP application using Eclipse 3.6 Helios. Now I have defined a Tag Library Definition called `DiceFunctions.tld` inside the `WEB-INF` folder, and then declared this in a jsp page like this -

`<%@taglib prefix="mine" uri="DiceFunctions"%>`

When I write en EL function call inside that JSP, I don't get any auto-complete/intellisense for the prefix `mine`, which means if I add 10-20 tag libraries in a page, then I will have to remember each one of their names so that I can call their methods. Also the method signature's auto-complete isn't working properly, I mean when I type `${mine: }` the IDE sometimes doesn't provide any suggestions for the functions defined inside that TLD. I need eclipse to provide intellisense for the tag library prefixes that I define and also for the functions defined within those TLDs. Also I couldn't find any way to create Tag Library Descriptor files (.tld) in eclipse. I had to create a general file and rename it so that it's extension becomes `.tld`.

Is there any way to modify eclipse to achieve those supports ? Is there a plugin which will be helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it myself but there is a plugin as part of the myeclipse suite which I have heard others rave about. They have a try-before-buy option. See http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-11.html

This also looks promising: http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor